# Create a text/plain Jersey response

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have some code that works, but I am looking for a better way to do it.  I have a RESTful web API that I want to support JSON, XML, and TEXT media types.  The JSON and XML is easy with a JAXB annotated "bean" class.  I just got **text/plain** to work, but I wish Jersey was a little more intelligent and would be able to convert a list of my beans, `List<Machine>` to a string using `toString`.

Here is the Resource class.  The JSON and XML media types use a JAXB annotated bean class.  The text plain uses a custom string format (basically the stdout representation of a command).

```
@Path("/machines")
public class MachineResource {
    private final MachineManager manager;

    @Inject
    public MachineResource(MachineManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @GET @Path("details/")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Machine> details() {
        return manager.details();
    }
    @GET @Path("details/")
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public String detailsText() {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();       
        for(Machine machine : manager.details()) {
            text.append(machine.toString());
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
```

**Is there a better way to do this with Jersey automatically converting to a string, so I only have to implement one method here?** (That can handle all 3 media types)

I see that I can implement a [MessageBodyWriter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e5256), but that seems like a lot more trouble.

#### EDIT:

If it matters, I am using the embedded Jetty and Jersey options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a `MessageBodyReader`/`Writer` would be what you need to do in order to do the following:

```
@GET @Path("details/")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public List<Machine> details() {
    return manager.details();
}
```

It's not very much code to write, and if you are able to write it generic enough you will be able to get some re-use out of it.

Comment: @Jess - Here is an example `MessageBodyReader`/`Writer`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: The reuse sounds promising.  I was looking at **Example 7.3** here:  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html.  The example makes it seem like I would have to create a `MessageBodyWriter` for each Bean (by calling it `MyBeanMessageBodyWriter`).  Is that a bad assumption on my part?

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe I could make all my beans implement an interface.  Then I can create one MessageBodyWriter like `implements MessageBodyWriter<MyBeanInterface>`.  In fact, the interface could require a toText() method and the MessageBodyWriter could simply call that?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. @Provider

For some reason the documentation does not mention that I need to annotate the `MessageBodyWriter` class with `@Provider`.  I have done that...

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class PlainTextWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Machine> {
```

... and now I see this message on start up.*  (Good)

```
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class com.blah.resources.PlainTextWriter
```

I still get the exception,

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, 
and Java type java.util.List<com.blah.beans.Machine>, 
and MIME media type text/plain was not found
```

- *Without @Provider, you get this message on start-up: `INFO: No provider classes found.`*

## 2. Use the correct type

The second part is that I was not implementing for the correct type.  I had a `List` of beans.  I assumed Jersey would be smart enough to understand how to serialize a list, but I guess it could do that in different ways.  Here was my second change: (Note the addition of `List`)

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class PlainTextWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<List<Machine>>
```

It is working now.  It's pretty cool because now I have a generic plain/text implementation.  I only have to implement the `toPlainText` method of my interface for each Bean.  No sweat!

## 3. Use the correct package.

It broke again.  Looking at the log I see this:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.my.project.resources
...
INFO: No provider classes found.
```

So I refactored my MessageBodyWriter into that package and it works again!